# Error while upgrading glassfish server 4.1.1 to glassfish server 5

Tags: hibernate-validator, glassfish-5

I am trying to upgrade the glassfish version but running in the following error:

```
Severe:   Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:962)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.markAllContainersAsStarted(EjbApplication.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1580)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.buildEjbInterceptorChain(InterceptorManager.java:431)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.<init>(InterceptorManager.java:131)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeInterceptorManager(BaseContainer.java:3432)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:950)
    ... 44 more

Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:962)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.markAllContainersAsStarted(EjbApplication.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1580)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.buildEjbInterceptorChain(InterceptorManager.java:431)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.<init>(InterceptorManager.java:131)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeInterceptorManager(BaseContainer.java:3432)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:950)
    ... 44 more

Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context 
Info:   /file:/E:/pradeep/TravelWeb/target/TravelWeb-3.0/WEB-INF/classes/_travelWebPU logout successful
Info:   No timers to be deleted for id: 101233299654967296
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1580)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.buildEjbInterceptorChain(InterceptorManager.java:431)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.<init>(InterceptorManager.java:131)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeInterceptorManager(BaseContainer.java:3432)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:950)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.markAllContainersAsStarted(EjbApplication.java:140)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Warning:
```

I have tried turning off the delegation and loading the required lib manually in the project but it didnt work and lead to another error.

```
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <class-loader delegate="false" />
</glassfish-web-app>
```

What I couldn't understand is that the hibernate validator is internal dependency to glassfish, so why there is a classnotfound exception.

I also tried resolving the issue by adding hibernate-validator-cdi dependency but then it led to duplicate classes error and I am not even using hibernate in my project.

Note: This is a maven project and is currently working in GF 4.1.1

Comment: I would just like to second your question. I am having the exact same problem simply by replacing GF 4.1.1 by GF 5. I even downloaded the absolute latest source version, which by now is the nightly build of 4th of January 2019. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason for this exception is following:
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22712
ValidationInterceptor class is already included into glassfish inside bean-validator-cdi.jar, but repackaged with wrong exported package name `org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor` instead of `org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor`. Fix from CarlosGoncalves should work because jar from hibernate export proper package, though for some reason it didn't for me.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I noticed your post on GF, well done. One can just correct the manifest within the bean-validator.cdi.jar and everything will just work without actually adding a new jar. I wonder why they haven't correct this yet as it has been like this for months! Also, welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

(Updated on 17/01/2019)

Back in my original answer I had found a workaround that would at least start the application when deployed into Glassfish. However, as predictable, it wouldn't do exactly what I intended and therefore it would soon break spectacularly as soon as you would actually need Bean Validation. So I dug a little deeper and I think I have found the correct way.

This problem arises because if you are using Glassfish then the default JAX-RS provider is Jersey and in turn, Jersey uses Hibernate Bean Validation. Now, since this is provided by GF it **should** work perfectly out-of-the-box, but apparently there is some dependency missing.

As such, the way to solve this (as stated [here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22317) in GF github repository) it merely to add **hibernate-validator-cdi-6.0.10.Final.jar** to your GF directoy **/glassfish/modules** and then restart your domain. The right module should be loaded, which will allow you to deploy your application and fully use Bean Validation.

This likely has something to do with a missing bundle in GF and I can confirm that it is still missing on Glassfish 5.1.0 RC.